# C++ ifstream/fstream corrupting data

Tags: c++, binary, fstream, ifstream

I'm new to C++ and I've to do an assignment for school.

I need to copy a binary* file without using api calls or system integrated commands. At school we use a windows machine.

I've searched around a bit, and I found out that the best way to copy data without using any api's is to use iostream (ifstream/fstream)
Here's the code I'm using:

```
int Open(string Name){

  int length;
  char * buffer;
  ifstream is;
  fstream out;
  FILE* pFile;
  is.open (Name.c_str(), ios::binary );

  // get length of file:
  is.seekg (0, ios::end);
  length = is.tellg();
  is.seekg (0, ios::beg);

  // allocate memory:
  buffer = new char [length];

  // read data as a block:
  is.read (buffer,length);
  is.close();

   pFile = fopen ( "out.exe" , "w" );
   fclose(pFile);

  out.open("out.exe", ios::binary);

  out.write( buffer, length);

  out.close();

  delete[] buffer;
  return 0;
}
```

out.exe isnt working properly, and after looking at it in winhex.exe
I see that the data has been modefied, while I'm not doing anything with it

Can anyone help me?

*the file is a simple hello world program, it messageboxes "hello world"

EDIT:

Sorry for my unresponsiveness, It was sleeping.
Anyways, I've opened both (the result and the original) programs inside an hex editor.
It seems that with everything I try this line:

```
Offset      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F

00000200   4C 00 00 00 00 30 00 00  00 02 00 00 00 0D 0A 00   L    0
```

Changes into this:

```
Offset      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F

00000200   4C 00 00 00 00 30 00 00  00 02 00 00 00 0A 00 00   L    0
```

As you can or cannot see somehow during the reading or writing process a byte is being removed (or added, that sometimes happens as well)

Comment: Have you tried looking at the resulting file in a hex editor to see where it went wrong?  Or copying, say, a text file, which would be easier to compare?

Comment: What kind of problems are you having?  What is up with the random fopen in the middle of your function?

Comment: How is it modified? How does the output differ from the input?

Comment: You should probably change `char` to `unsigned char`

Comment: Actually char is fine here. Sorry spartan018.

Comment: 0D 0A transformed into 0A is carriage-return linefeed transformed into linefeed. Are you really sure that you use the binary flag when reading *and* writing?

Comment: Yes, as you can still see I'm using the ios::binary flag

Comment: Possibly not the cause of your problem but: Passing `ios_base::binary` to `fstream`'s ctor is not specified (`in` and/or `out` must be supplied too). Use `ofstream` (note the exra 'o') for `out` instead of `fstream`. As a bonus, this would avoid the need to first `fopen` with the "w" flag since `ofstream`'s ctor creates the file by default.

Comment: if you make that into an answer I can accept you, because it's working! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Passing *only* `ios_base::binary` to `fstream`'s ctor is not specified (`in` and/or `out` must be supplied too).

To avoid that, you could use `ofstream` (note the exra 'o') for `out` instead of `fstream`. As a bonus, this would avoid the need to first `fopen` with the "w" flag since `ofstream`'s ctor creates the file by default.

Answer (score 1):

is.read(buffer, length) is not guaranteed to read length bytes.

I forget if the same is true for out.write or not.

Comment: +1. You need to call `is.gcount()` to tell how many bytes were read.

Comment: but he has checked the length with seekg(),tellg() and he has used ios::binary flag which should ensure EOF doesn't come with any binary 0 but real EOF.

Comment: Knowing there are len bytes to read does not suffice to assume that a read of len bytes actually reads len bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Lets make that a bit neater:

```
// Pass strings by const reference (just good habit)
// But may also save a copy. And it indicates that the function should
// not be messing with the name!
int Open(std::string const& Name, std::string const& out)
{
  // Declare variables as close to use as possable.
  // It is very C-Like to declare all the variables at the
  // head of a function.

  // Use the constructor to open the file.
  std::ifstream is(Name.c_str(), ios::binary);
  if (!is) // Failed to open
  {    return -1;
  }

  // get length of file:
  is.seekg (0, ios::end);
  std::size_t length = is.tellg();  // Use the correct type. int is not correct
  is.seekg (0, ios::beg);

  // allocate memory:
  // Using new/delete is risky. It makes the code not exception safe.
  // Also because you have to manually tidy up the buffer you can not
  // escape early. By using RAII the cleanup becomes automative and there
  // is no need to track resources that need to be tidied.
  // 
  // Look up the concept of RAII it makes C++ lfe so much easier.
  // std::vector implements the new/delete internally using RAII
  std::vector<char>    buffer(length);

  std::size_t  read = 0;
  do
  {
      // read does not gurantee that it will read everything asked for.
      // so you need to do int a loop if you want to read the whole thing
      // into a buffer.
      is.read(&buffer[read], length - read);
      std::size_t amount = is.gcount();
      if (amount == 0)
      {    return -2; // Something went wrong and it failed to read.
      }
      read += amount;
  } while(length != read);


  fstream out(out.c_str(), ios::binary );
  if (!out)
  {    return -3; // you may want to test this before spending all the time reading
  }


  // Probably need to loop like we did for read.
  out.write( &buffer[0], length);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code's result doesn't differ from mine, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @Dean glow: Its supposed to look like yours. But tidied up and made neater.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, files end in a newline.  That 0d0a ("\r\n") might not be a readable part of the source file.  Windows usually uses "\r\n" for newline, while UNIX uses just "\n".  For some reason, when it writes a new file, it's using just 0a for the final newline.  It might be interesting to see what happens if you read in and copy the file you wrote the first time.

The short answer is, this is just the kind of problem that crops up when you use a Windows system. :D

To hack it, you could always unconditionally write an extra "\r" as the last thing you output.

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
ifstream src(source.c_str(), ios::binary);
ofstream dest(destination.c_str(), ios::binary | ios::trunc);
dest << src.rdbuf();
src.close();
dest.close();
```

would do the trick.

Comment: No need to explicitly call close unless you want to check for errors (and if you are not checking then dont). Let it fall out of scope and the destructor will tidy up.